# Is it even possible in Excel to check for duplicates in column A and then compare the corresponding dates in column B?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I normally never ask anything but I've hit a wall. I don't even know if this is possible at all.

Lets say column A is a list of student# and Column B is a list of dates that each student phone the university. i.e:

```
123456  9/21/2013
123456  9/22/2013
123456  9/25/2013
124343  10/10/2014
324242  11/15/2014
```

So student with ID 123456 called in 3 times. But I want to specifically be able to calculate is if there is more than one call for a student, how many times did he call back within 48 hours of the original call. The answer here would be that 123456 called back 1 time within 48 hours of the first occurrence.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into problems? What kind of output format do you need?  This is a solvable problem, but this group is for helping others develop code, not for providing it.

Comment: It was actually a mistake on my part. Poor wording. I was able to calculate how many times a certain student called but I had no idea  how I would go about calculating how many times they did so in the last 48 hours, couldn't wrap my head around it for some reason. And the first answer was indeed all I needed. Thanks again!!

Comment: Please don't accept answers so quickly! As you'll see from my answer, the result can probably be attained without any VBA coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in A2 (row 1 being used for headings), then try the following formula in C2 and copy it down:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,">"&B2,B:B,"<="&B2+2)
```

That says "Count all cases where the value is col A is the current student and where the date is between the date on the current row and 2 days into the future".

If it possible that there are multiple calls on the same day, then this might be better:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,">="&B2,B:B,"<="&B2+2)-1
```

(the `-1` removes the match of each row against itself from the count).

If the 48 hours needs to be more precise then you might need to vary the formula to work with hours rather than just days, but the same formula structure should work.

Comment: I was bout to post the same suggestion. Beat me to it :)

Comment: I'm SMH'ing so much right now. I spent hours today trying different COUNTIF formulas. I even tried putting IF before the countIF and then outputting the amount of times called if true but I couldn't figure out how to say within 2 days.

I just wanted to say this is also extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Smile, it's possible :)

First you get all the students' IDs (no duplicates) into a collection (assuming they start from Range("A1") onwards):

```
Dim studentsID As New Collection
For j = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    alreadyThere = False 
    For k = 1 To studentsID.Count
        If Range("A" & j) = studentsID(k) Then
            alreadyThere = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next k
    If alreadyThere = False Then studentsID.Add Range("A" & j).Value 'if student is not there yet, add it to the collection
Next j
```

**THIS COUNTS HOW MANY TIMES A STUDENT CALLED IN TOTAL** ... because you have asked *But I want to specifically be able to calculate is if there is more than one call for a student*

So you check if there is more than one call from the student:

```
For j = 1 To studentsID.Count 'for each student in your list
    count = 0
    For k = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Range("A" & k) = studentsID(j) Then count = count + 1 'count how many occurrencies there are in column A    
    Next k
    If count > 1 Then MsgBox "The student " & studentsID(j) & " called us " & count & " times"
Next j
```

**WHILE THIS COUNTS HOW MANY TIMES A STUDENT CALLED IN THE LAST 48 HOURS**

...and following the same logic you count how many times he called during the last 48 hrs:

```
todayIs = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now()))
twoDaysAgoWas = todayIs - 2 
For j = 1 To studentsID.Count
    count = 0
    For k = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If (Range("A" & k) = studentsID(j)) And (Range("B" & k) >= twoDaysAgoWas) Then count = count + 1    
    Next k
    If count > 1 Then MsgBox "The student " & studentsID(j) & " called us " & count & " times during the last 48 hours."
Next j
```

You can play around with these code snippets to build your desired output (for example, rather than using the messageboxes you most probably want to store the counters in variables and print them into a stats sheet).

**NOTE**

If you need the **exact** last 48 hours, you might want as well to use the function `TimeSerial(Hour,Minute,Second)`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I appreciate it. Definitely the right path there and I probably wouldn't have figured that out and I'm beginning to understand it. I'm still a bit new to incorporating VBA into my spreadsheets. For fun I tested all your code and it showed dialogue boxes that showed the total times a student called rather than just within the last 48 hours. Not sure why though.